# Adding custom Magento menu

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I've looked for literally over an hour and cannot find an answer to a seemingly simple task. I want to add links to a custom menu that link to pages within Magento, as opposed to a category page.

Does anyone have an answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you want to add the link? Have you tried using static blocks (CMS -> Static Blocks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want it to automatically generate the page links?

If not you could just use a static block to create your menu, and then add the block to your layout.

1) Create a new static block with name: **left_menu** andd add the HTML to the static block.

2) Add this layout update to show the block in the left column:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="cms/block" name="left_menu_block" before="-">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_menu</block_id></action>
    </block>    
</reference>
```